# Why are random div tags appearing on my sites when on a local test server?

Tags: php, html, xss, mamp

I'm writing my sites in Dreamweaver and using MAMP in order to run a local testing server. Upon first running MAMP (on the default configuration page for MAMP) I started getting strange alerts that I didn't really understand. These would appear upon reloading the page or navigating to it:
[image]
[image]

I didn't think anything of it, but then when I started using it as a local testing server, I noticed these little footers being added to all my sites:
[image]
Upon closer examination, this was all I could find:
[image]

I truly just don't understand what's going on. I'm relatively new to using test-servers and I've never run MAMP before. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance, 
Zach.

Comment: Pictures are nice but please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: I've done some quick searching and depending on the age of your Dreamweaver it's adding XSSME (cross site scripting) protection/checking by default. See some info on it here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25193422/Need-Help-Protecting-Website-from-Cross-Site-Scripting.html. But you don't need this code, especially on your local, so simply remove it. You'll notice most mentions of this are quite old, nearly ten years old in fact. You can test for XSS attacks but your web server is responsible for this now: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: If you're using dreamweaver, please do not use design or split view.

Comment: It's not in my code unfortunately. It appears to be added by the test server. I've found it when inspecting the source of the locally hosted page, but in all of my copies of the code (including when I do a browser preview/live view preview from Dreamweaver) it doesn't appear to exist.